# Re-running macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that clears out the previous content and replaces with new information. I needed to adjust for more or less rows which I was able to successfully code. The one problem I have is that if my previous data was less than my new data it takes a couple of re-runs for it to grab all the information. how can I fix my code to make sure all the new data is grabbed.

```
Worksheets("Before n After Remap Review").Range("A7:E" & LastRow).Select
Selection.ClearContents

Worksheets("Before n After Remap Review").Range("I7:J" & LastRow).Select
Selection.ClearContents

Workbooks("before_n_after_remap_audit_umroi.txt").Worksheets("before_n_after_remap_audit_umro").Range("A1:E" & LastRow).Copy
Workbooks("UMROI_Standard Cost Audit Reports.xlsm").Worksheets("Before n After Remap Review").Range("A7:E" & LastRow).PasteSpecial

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Workbooks("before_n_after_remap_audit_umroi.txt").Worksheets("before_n_after_remap_audit_umro").Range("F1:G" & LastRow).Copy
Workbooks("UMROI_Standard Cost Audit Reports.xlsm").Worksheets("Before n After Remap Review").Range("I7:J" & LastRow).PasteSpecial

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to either:

1. re-determine `LastRow` each time you're working with a different worksheet, or
2. have a `LastRow` variable for each worksheet.

## Helper function

I assume you are using the `Rows.Count` and `.End(xlUp)` method of determining the LastRow.

```
Function FindLastRow(ByRef ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal col As Variant = "A") As Long

    FindLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

## Option 1

```
Sub Option1()

    Dim sheetTarget As Worksheet, sheetSource As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set sheetTarget = Workbooks("UMROI_Standard Cost Audit Reports.xlsm").Worksheets("Before n After Remap Review") ' our target sheet
    Set sheetSource = Workbooks("before_n_after_remap_audit_umroi.txt").Worksheets("before_n_after_remap_audit_umro") ' our source sheet
'    Set sheetTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
'    Set sheetSource = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

    LastRow = FindLastRow(sheetTarget) ' last row of our target sheet, based on column A (default)
    sheetTarget.Range("A7:E" & LastRow).ClearContents ' clear our target sheet
    sheetTarget.Range("I7:J" & LastRow).ClearContents ' clear our target sheet

    LastRow = FindLastRow(sheetSource) ' last row of our source sheet, based on column A (default)
    sheetSource.Range("A1:E" & LastRow).Copy ' copy our source range

    ' we need the size of the target range to paste to, and we need to calculate this based on source LastRow
    LastRow = LastRow + 7 - 1 ' the target range starts at row 7 (A7), the source range starts at row 1 (A1)
    sheetTarget.Range("A7:E" & LastRow).PasteSpecial ' paste to our target range

    ' we are grabbing from the source again, so we need to recalculate source LastRow
    LastRow = FindLastRow(sheetSource) ' last row of our source sheet, based on column A (default)
    sheetSource.Range("F1:G" & LastRow).Copy

    ' we need the size of the target range to paste to, and we need to calculate this based on source LastRow
    LastRow = LastRow + 7 - 1 ' the target range starts at row 7 (A7), the source range starts at row 1 (A1)
    sheetTarget.Range("I7:J" & LastRow).PasteSpecial

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

## Option 2

```
Sub Option2()

    Dim sheetTarget As Worksheet, sheetSource As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowT As Long, LastRowS As Long

    Set sheetTarget = Workbooks("UMROI_Standard Cost Audit Reports.xlsm").Worksheets("Before n After Remap Review") ' our target sheet
    Set sheetSource = Workbooks("before_n_after_remap_audit_umroi.txt").Worksheets("before_n_after_remap_audit_umro") ' our source sheet
'    Set sheetTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
'    Set sheetSource = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

    LastRowT = FindLastRow(sheetTarget) ' last row of our target sheet, based on column A (default)
    sheetTarget.Range("A7:E" & LastRowT).ClearContents ' clear our target sheet
    sheetTarget.Range("I7:J" & LastRowT).ClearContents ' clear our target sheet
    ' our target sheet is cleared, we no longer need to work with LastRowT

    LastRowS = FindLastRow(sheetSource) ' last row of our source sheet, based on column A (default)

    sheetSource.Range("A1:E" & LastRowS).Copy ' copy our source range

    ' while we don't work with LastRowT anymore, we still need the size of the target range to paste to, and we need to calculate this based on LastRowS
    LastRowT = LastRowS + 7 - 1 ' the target range starts at row 7 (A7), the source range starts at row 1 (A1)

    sheetTarget.Range("A7:E" & LastRowT).PasteSpecial ' paste to our target range

    sheetSource.Range("F1:G" & LastRowS).Copy
    sheetTarget.Range("I7:J" & LastRowT).PasteSpecial

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

## Alternatively...

Consider working with ranges directly, instead of building a new range with LastRow each time.